# Next/image giving 502 error in production

Tags: next.js, vercel, nextjs-image, notion-api

In my website, I use Notion as a CMS, from where I fetch images via Notion APIs, and use the next/image component to show the images. Almost half of the time I get a `502` error and the images are not displayed. What is causing this?

[image: getting 502 errors]

502 error message:

[image: 502 error message]

Vercel logs show a mix of both 200 and 502 codes
[image: vercel logs]

My next config file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = {
    nextConfig,
    images: {
        domains: ["s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "raw.githubusercontent.com"],
    },
};
```

The [learn how to fix the error](https://vercel.com/docs/error/application/OPTIMIZED_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_REQUEST_UNAUTHORIZED) link on error page just leads to a broken 404 page

Also, I've already configured the project to use the `sharp` package for image optimization.

Comment: This might happen because your image is not public. Try to access the URL in incognito window

Comment: I can access the images, its like I said sometimes I get 200, sometimes I get 502

Comment: I think we needed more context in terms of code or reproduction example or maybe your site URL so we could have a better understanding from your POV.

Comment: Site url : https://dhruvkulkarni.vercel.app/  Repo url: https://github.com/DhruvKulkarni86/portfolio